# How to change texture from pvr.ccz in Cocos2d?

Tags: textures, cocos2d, cocos2d-x

I'm using .pvr.ccz file that texturePacker application created for me , I created a Sprite that it's image choosed from this file(.pvr.ccz) like below:

```
  CCSprite *mySprite = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("first.png");
```

But how can I change it's texture using .pvr.ccz file?

I knew below solution for changing texture of a sprite, but it works when second.png file is normal PNG file and is not compressed in a.pvr.ccz file.

```
mySprite->setTexture(CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImage("second.png"));
```